# Википедия

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Прошу простить мне мою дремучесть, но почему интернет-энциклопения называется "википедия"? Что означает часть слова "вики"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Название энциклопедии образовано от английских слов wiki (вики, технология, лежащая в основе функционирования сайта; в свою очередь заимствовано из гавайского языка, в котором оно имеет значение «быстро») и encyclopedia (энциклопедия).*
©Вики

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Я тоже ничего об этом не знаю. На этом форуме мы тоже можем, как сказано в правилах, открывать вики-вопросы (правильно ли я написала?), я из контекста как-то поняла суть, но не уверена, что правильно.

Comment: Да вроде все понятно и достаточно полно. wiki - на гавайском "быстро", "педия" - учить, узнавать (от "педос" - ребенок), взято из "энциклопедия".